# Как передать дочернему окну значения?

Tags: javascript

Открываю окно через `window.open(smth, , , )`, все нормально; а потом мне нужно, нажав в главном окне на ссылку или кнопку передать, значение в дочернее. А вот как обратиться к дочернему окну? Перепробовал уже много способов, найденных в Интернете, и не получается.
Конкретно мне нужно передать такое значение `.uppodSend('id','file:rytr.mp3')`, обращаясь к плееру, который находится в дочернем окне.

Answer (score 4):

А не пробовали воспользоваться ссылкой на новое окно, который метод `open()` использует в качестве возвращаемого результата? У нового также есть объект `document`, с помощью него Вы и сможете передать это значение.

Ссылка будет выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
var newWindow = window.open(bla-bla);
newWindow.document.getElemntById('bla')....
```

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно дочерним окном взять значение из родительского, например так:

```
var ParentText = window.opener.document.getElementById('parentText').value;
```

И для jquery, необходимо передать родителя как второй параметр:

```
var ParentText = $("parentText", window.opener.document);
```

Либо обращаться непосредственно к jquery родительского окна:

```
var ParentText = window.opener.jQuery("[name=abc]");
```

Comment: а как второе окно поймёт, что "пора забирать" это значение?

Comment: Например по таймеру, а в родительском окне будет меняться что-либо, что и будет опрашиваться ребенком.

Comment: Правильный usecase: открыли дочернее окно, сделали все что нужно, в родительском проверили что сделано интерпретировали результат. см. ответ @LeD4eG

Answer (score 0):

Недавно столкнулся с этой проблемой. Только у меня была обратная задача, необходимо было открыть дочернее окно, а оно должно было вернуть значение в открывший его элемент. Достиг этого таким образом:

На родительском окне:

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="result"></span>
    <a href="/listSelect" class="select">Выбрать</a>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".container .select").click(function(){
            window.open($(this).attr('href'), 'xxx');
            window.onSelect = function(text){
                $(this).closest('.container').children('.result').html(text);
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Ссылка /listSelect ведет к содержимому дочернего окна.
На дочернем окне отображается:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li><button data-text="Значение1" value="Вариант1" /></li>
    <li><button data-text="Значение2" value="Вариант2" /></li>
    <li><button data-text="Значение3" value="Вариант3" /></li>
    <li><button data-text="Значение4" value="Вариант4" /></li>
</ul>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".list button").click(function(){
                var text = $(this).attr('data-text');
                if(window.opener.onSelect) window.opener.onSelect(text);
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Таким образом при создании дочернего окна я у родительского окна создавал функцию, вызывая которую дочернее окно возвратит результат.

В твоем случае надо поступить примерно также:

Создать на дочернем окне функцию переключения плеера с применением входящих аргументов, а родительское окно должно будет при соответствующем событии поискать функцию в дочернем окне (Дочернее окно может быть и не открыто, когда происходит действие, которое должно приводить к переключению плеера).